# Symbolic Nullspace computation in parallel

Tags: symbolic, linear-algebra, parallelization

I am trying to determine the nullspace of a large symbolic matrix. The single core evolution seems to take too long. I tried `Parallelize[]` on the commands  `LinearSolve[]` and on `NullSpace[]` without success. I got messages like

> NullSpace[M] cannot be parallelized; proceeding with sequential \
>   evaluation

Is there any way to parallise the computation of the Nullspace? My only idea is to slice the matrix like

```
Matrix[[1+k;;100+k,All]]
```

and then to compute the nullspace for each slice. Then calculate the intersection of the nullspaces as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25371/how-to-find-basis-for-intersection-of-two-vector-spaces) (maybe there is a more efficient way than to do this).

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: I am pretty certain the performance of the built in algorithms are not easy improved. There may be a way to improve performance, depending on the structure of the matrix. Unfortunately you do not provide any information on that (other than large and symbolic). It would help if you can indicate how sparse the matrix is and whether there are many repeated sub-elements.

Comment: It is not about improving built-in algorithm. The built-in algorithm works only sequentially. Therefore it is conceivable that applying Nullspace in parallel to slices and the intersecting them is faster than just one sequential computaiton.

Comment: There is a method posted [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6776/space-efficient-null-space-of-sparse-array). Alternatively, find null spaces of certain submatrices and find the intersection of the result.

Comment: Do you know what the most efficient way to compute these intersections would be?

Comment: Be aware that `NullSpace` **does** use a multithreading algorithm (check MKL) which, in your case as you are using **symbolic** matrices, does indeed become sequential operation. You will continue to run into complications when paralellizing `NullSpace`; as it is already multi threaded so you are unlikely to avoid the conflicts you are introducing (in other words, the `warning` that `NullSpace[M] cannot be parallelized` has a specific meaning). You probably need to write your own `NullSpace` equivalent function if you need to go parallel to avoid that constraint.

Comment: Here is a problem that runs for days, with CPU never >100% (no sign of parallel). I too would like a) better performance and b) greater trustworthiness in its output - no result from Mathematica 11.0.0, but a questionable one with a vector of zeroes except for a 1 in the 7th from last element. I hope that it helps the OP get an answer to their question. Note that the NullSpace command can bring a 16Gb system to its knees for lack of memory. 22Gb required, but still a long wait for a possibly incorrect answer. F = {{0, f12, f13, f14, f15}, {f21, 0, f23, f24, f25}, {f31, f32, 0, f34, f35}, {f41,

Comment: Looks to be intractable.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/53225)