# Eigenvector Concern in Large Fractal-Like Matrix (Possible Bug?)

Tags: linear-algebra

This is my first post and I have quite a long question. Thanks to any who read.

To start with, I have an operator m=Transpose[n] on a 7 dimensional vector space V where n is constructed as follows:

```
v = {1, 0, 0, 0, a, 0, b, a, c, 0, g, d, e, g};
n = NestList[Delete[Prepend[#, 0], -1] &, v, 13];
```

I desire to calculate a basis of the eigenspace for the induced map of m on the 7th exterior power V. To this end I created the induced matrix M3 with the following code:

```
h[{i_, j_, k_, o_, p_, u_, y_}] :=n[[i]]\[TensorWedge]n[[j]]\[TensorWedge]n[[k]]\[TensorWedge]n[[
o]]\[TensorWedge]n[[p]]\[TensorWedge]n[[u]]\[TensorWedge]n[[y]];

OrderedTuples = Flatten[Table[{i, j, k, o, p, u, y}, {i, 8}, {j, i + 1, 9}, {k, 
 j + 1, 10}, {o, k + 1, 11}, {p, o + 1, 12}, {u, p + 1, 13}, {y, 
 u + 1, 14}], 6];


M = Map[h, OrderedTuples];

M2 = Map[Drop[SymmetrizedArrayRules[#], -1] &, M];

Rules = {};

For[i = 1, i < Length[M] + 1, i++, Print[i]; 
ComposeRule[rulelist_] := rulelist /. HoldPattern[Rule[x_,y_]] :> (x /.Thread[OrderedTuples -> Thread[{i, Range[Length[M]]}]]) -> y;
AppendTo[Rules, Map[ComposeRule, M2[[i]]]]];

M3 = Transpose[Normal[SparseArray[Flatten[Rules], {Length[OrderedTuples], Length[OrderedTuples]}, 0]]];
```

It takes about an hour to make M3 on my machine (very rough estimate).

Truly, I am interested in the intersection of the eigenspaces (The only eigenvalue of M3 is 1 and if you plot the entries of M3 you see it is like a Sierpenski Gasket, hence the fractal part of the title) over all values of the parameters a,b,c,d,e,g. To start off chose some fixed values like

```
a = -1236;
b = 5423;
c = 2134;
d = -5453;
e = 2234;
f = 4325;
g = -237;
```

because sufficiently general parameters should catch all the eigenvectors. To calculate the eignespace I used:

```
Eigen = DeleteDuplicates[Eigenvectors[N[M3]]];
```

and obtained a list of 14 eigenvectors, all of which are basis elements. To see this observe that

```
Length[Eigen]

14

For[i = 1, i < Length[Eigen] + 1, i++, 
Print[DeleteDuplicates[Eigen[[i]]]]]

{0.,1.}

{0.,1.}

{0.}

{0.,1.}

{0.,1.}

{0.,1.}

{0.,1.}

{0.,1.}

{0.,1.}

{0.,1.}

{0.,1.}

{0.,1.}

{0.,1.}

{0.,1.}
```

and

```
For[i = 1, i < Length[Eigen] + 1, i++, Print[Count[Eigen[[i]], 1.]]]

1

1

0

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1

1
```

Also, I can see exactly which basis vectors these are with

```
Pos = Sort[Flatten[Map[Position[#, 1.] &, Eigen]]]

{3092, 3311, 3388, 3394, 3396, 3417, 3421, 3423, 3424, 3429, 3430, 3431, 3432}
```

Now here is the interesting part: From the context of the problem (Algebraic Geometry) I know that

```
E = SparseArray[{{1603, 1} -> 1, {1606, 1} -> 1, {1695, 1} -> -1, {1698, 1} -> -1}, {3432, 1}];
```

Should be an eigenvector of M3 and indeed,

```
ArrayRules[M3.Normal[E]]

{{1603, 1} -> 1, {1606, 1} -> 1, {1695, 1} -> -1, {1698, 1} -> -1, {_, _} -> 0}
```

as I thought it should be. Is this a bug? Why isn't mathematica producing a basis for the eigenspace? Also, I exported the matrix to matlab and it also calculated the eigenvectors wrong and gave essentially the same answer.

Thanks again!

Ian

Edit 1: I wanted to point out that when I do the same procedure for much smaller cases mathematica is able to give me results that make sense in the bigger theory and this is why it appears to be a scaling issue. Also I have added the following picture to show the fractal structure

[image]

Edit 2: I have used

```
Export["M3.mtx", SparseArray[M3]]
```

as J.M. requested. To create a compressed sparse array version of M3. Here is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8fg8rmtrv494fve/M3.mtx?dl=0

Comment: Ian, you put together a nice question and thorough background, but I wonder if you might be able to extract a *minimal example* that reproduces the issue you are experiencing. As it stands, the sheer length and complexity of your problem might decrease your chances to get help.

Comment: Hi MarcoB, thanks for the feedback. I have been trying to construct a similar example using rotation matrices just to see if the scale is the problem. So far this is to no avail.

Comment: If *Mathematica* and MATLAB both have the same problem, it is possibly an MKL issue. Which version of both packages did you test?

Comment: *Mathematica* 10.2 uses MKL 11.2 Update 2. Do you know which version MATLAB is using? Also, it would be helpful if you could state which processor you have. Bug fixes for MKL 11.2 are listed [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-112-bug-fixes), but nothing seems relevant to this issue. Please try another version of *Mathematica* or MATLAB, if possible, or alternatively `Compress` your matrix `M3` and upload it somewhere for others to work with, rather than waiting 1 hour to generate it?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong about my last post I will edit when I can. I use 10.0.1 for mathematica and 8.6 for MATLAB. My processor is 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5.

Comment: Good Jove, did you actually upload a compressed *dense* array? I suggest redoing it as `Export["M3.mtx", SparseArray[M3]]` and then upload it again.

Comment: I changed it as you requested J.M.

Answer (score 7):

You are new, and this is a difficult problem you have been working on. So I'll try to point out some ways to make things easier.

(1) Try to make the code as simple as possible. Little things help. I'll show a few in a moment.

(2) Don't use things like `n` for matrices.

(3) Don't use upper cases things that look like built-in functions, for example `Rules`, as variables.

(4) For that matter, don't use  upper cases things that look like built-in functions, for example `ComposeRule`, as a function.

(5) Maybe consider modestly descriptive names for variables, e.g. `vec` and `mat`. Not essential, but certainly helpful when you want debugging advice from others.

(6) Try to avoid "global" variables in functions you are defining. Again, not really essential but helpful for others trying to debug.

The next few lines set up the matrix and `TensorWedge` definitions.

```
vec = {1, 0, 0, 0, a, 0, b, a, c, 0, g, d, e, g};
mat = NestList[Prepend[Most[#], 0] &, vec, 13];
hh[ilist : {_Integer ..}, m_] := TensorWedge @@ m[[ilist]]
```

After considerable wrangling with your definitions, attempting on smaller examples, I think I decided that you are taking all 7-minors of the 14×14 original matrix, and placing them in your new matrix. That is to say, I believe your `M3` is going to be the same as `dwarves` (aka "seven miners") below. (Among other things, this means we don't even need the definition for `hh` above, or any other explicit use of `TensorWedge`. All the churning through sparse and structured array innards likewise disappears.)

```
Timing[dwarves = Minors[mat, 7];]

(* Out[182]= {29.161219, Null} *)

Dimensions[dwarves]

(* Out[184]= {3432, 3432} *)
```

Now for eigenstructure. Notice I made one value approximate so everything will be done in machine arithmetic.

```
rep = {a -> -1236, b -> 5423., c -> 2134, d -> -5453, e -> 2234, 
   f -> 4325, g -> -237};

Timing[es = Eigensystem[dwarves /. rep];]

(* Out[494]= {31.953408, Null} *)
```

We did this using machine double libraries. So we might or might not get something viable. What I obtain below appears to have 13 independent eigenvectors.

```
evals = es[[1]];
Length[evals]
Union[evals]

(* Out[499]= 3432

Out[500]= {1.} *)

evecs = es[[2]];
maxes = Map[Max[Abs[#]] &, evecs];
posns = Position[maxes, Except[0.], {1}, Heads -> False]

(* Out[497]= {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {9}, {10}, {12}, {16}, {37}, {39}, 
              {45}, {122}, {341}} *)
```

So that's where I am thus far. If I can make more sense of the eigencomputations I'll edit with an update. Not sure anything has gone wrong though, unless general theory suggests 13 would be, well, an unlucky count.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks a lot for your advice. Sorry for giving my objects potentially awkward names. My computation also gave 13 eigenvectors, all of which were elements of the chosen basis. The general theory suggests that there should be more (such as the one I gave and showed was an eigenvector). I appreciate your efforts on this problem.

Comment: On the bright side, you can now get the wrong result much faster.

Comment: Is it bad that I upvoted because of `dwarves`? :)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau My original matrix is the transpose of the quick one you created. You can now check that `ArrayRules[Transpose[dwarves].Normal[
   SparseArray[{{1603, 1} -> 1, {1606, 1} -> 1, {1695, 1} -> -1, {1698, 1} -> -1}, {3432, 1}]]]` indeed gives an eigenvector not on on the list of the ones `Eigenvectors` computed for me.

Comment: Serious suggestion 1 (which I can't try just yet). Change the replacement rule to be exact. Use `nmat=N[...,100]` on the matrix. If this does not exhaust your RAM (or it does, but maybe you also have (crudity/vulgarity warning duly posted) [a good goat](http://brazenbilly.blogspot.com/2006/02/good-goat.html), then try `Eigensystem[nmat,20]` and see if the higher precision causes more independent vectors to show up.

Comment: `3432 - MatrixRank[m3 - SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 1.}, 3432]]` $=3074$ and considering that the matrix  is unsymmetric, I will not be terribly surprised if `m3` is *defective* (or numerically close to a defective one), which might explain the missed eigenvectors.

Comment: Serious suggestion 2: You know already the only eigenvalue is 1. Say we call the matrix `dwarves`, with exact values substituted `smat`.Try to find the exact `NullSpace[smat-IdentityMatrix[Length[smat]]]`. If that is too much in terms of computational load, I can come up with a skinny SVD approach next.

Comment: @J.M. I'll ask Grumpy.

Comment: @J.M. If by _defective_ you mean that it does not have a basis of eigenvectors then you are correct (again from the context of the siutation). But as you can see _Mathematica_ is still missing some.

Comment: @Ian, well, not a *complete* basis set, that is. "*Mathematica* is still missing some" - that's actually the point; eigensystem methods will have trouble with (nearly-)defective matrices.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau @J.M. Thanks, I have not come across the notion of a complete basis set before. I am trying the suggestions that Daniel posted above. What is `smat` above; should it be `nmat`?

Comment: A thing I cannot seem to get straight at the moment is whether it is defective, or derogatory, that can give numeric methods fits. I have a recollection it is the latter class that tends to cause the more troubles. Certainly that is true for the algebraic eigendecomposition approach used in algebraic systems `NSolve` (the default method in versions 4-9).

Comment: @Ian, to recap: `dwarves` is the symbolic matrix Daniel derived, which you say is the transpose of your `M3`. Plug-in exact values (no `N[]`!) of those parameters, and call that matrix `smat`. (I can't do that test myself, my computer's severely underpowered.)

Comment: Right. To spell out, `smat=dwarves /. exactrep`, where `exactrep={a -> -1236, b -> 5423, c -> 2134, d -> -5453, e -> 2234, 
   f -> 4325, g -> -237}` assuming I made no typo errors. And as @J.M. reminds, you actually want to work with `Transpose[smat]`.

Comment: (For the kids at home watching the proceedings, [here](https://doi.org/10.1137/1002025)'s a program.) Daniel: derogatory matrices should be fine; more so if they're actually diagonalizable. Defective ones I have much less hope for.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think I will run out of RAM doing the exact calculations. I have access to a cluster which I will try to run the computation on tomorrow.

Comment: @J.M. No, it's derogatory ones that are worse, to my recollection. But that's based on experience with certain types of problem and maybe is not generally how it goes.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I ran the nullspace command on the cluster and it took about 40 gb of RAM. I reduced the numbers to make the output smaller but it was still 200 mb and the vector I demonstrated was on the list. Many of the eigenvectors depended on the parameters and don't matter in my context. Thanks a lot Daniel!

Comment: I don't know if this will help but a null space can be done in a [divide-and-conquer manner](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6776/space-efficient-null-space-of-sparse-array). I did in fact try this but eventually got a crash, presumably from overrunning RAM. I was using exact integer arithmetic and maybe it would have done fine with, say mid-to-large fixed precision e.g. a few hundred digits.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I might try that. The eigenvectors the cluster listed using the NullSpace command were the 13 which were found numerically plus the extra one I mentioned. Since then I have found one additional eigenvector that even the exact computation failed to find, 'SparseArray[{{2991, 1} -> 1, {3015, 1} -> -1, {3083, 1} -> 
   1, {3098, 1} -> 1}, {3432, 1}]'. Seems like when I notice eigenvectors the computer can find them...

Comment: You may have discovered some sort of antithesis to [quantum locking](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Quantum-locking). As for getting an incomplete set of null space generators using exact methods, I am at a loss (I assume you checked that the new one was not in the span of the rest).