# Finding the null space of a large sparse matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, sparse-arrays

I am trying to compute the null space of a large $n\times n$ sparse matrix. No matter how large the dimension of the matrix is, it will always look like as below:

[image]

The figure on the left shows the version of the matrix for with 10-dimension and the right panel is the ~1700 version. As can be seen, it will always be a very sparse matrix and I'm trying to find its null space. Are there any suggestions on what would be the most efficient way to do so? Or at least, is `NullSpace[]` the most efficient tool in this case?

In terms of dimensionality, I'm aiming to go as high as the computational power of Mathematica allows me. I have already seen the question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/156515/find-nullspace-of-a-very-sparse-symbolic-matrix) and I also have tried RowReduce as well, but I'm always getting the error "Result for RowReduce of badly conditioned matrix". Nullspace seems to work fine (albeit slow), at least up to n~40000 that I've tried so far.

**Update**

[Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ya6me0meb1r638/SparseMatrix-NullSpace.nb?dl=0) to a notebook that generates the matrix.

Comment: Indeed, `NullSpace` should be the way to go. Maybe `Eigensystem[A, -1, Method->"Arnoldi"]` with suitable shift might also help. But as always, it depends on your concrete matrix. Would you please share the code that generates it?

Comment: Curious what it looks like inverted. Structure often begets structure...

Comment: Thank you for your comments! @HenrikSchumacher, yes absolutely! The code that generates the actual elements of the matrix is off of a much longer code which might be too complicated and too long. In this notebook, I have generated those numbers randomly, but the structure of the matrix is the same. In the actual case, det is always zero from the physics of the problem, here I've made the elements small enough so that the null space would be guaranteed. I tried to make as many comments as possible to clarify each step: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ya6me0meb1r638/SparseMatrix-NullSpace.nb?dl=0

Comment: Hmm. Apparently, `{lambda, u} = Eigensystem[NullMatrix, -1, Method -> {"Arnoldi"}];` works fine. `u[[1]]` seems to be the only null vector. Or do you expect more than one? Then you can do, e.g., `{lambda, u} = Eigensystem[NullMatrix, -20, Method -> {"Arnoldi"}];` and check the vector `lambda` of eigenvalues for zero (or near-zero) entries.

Comment: Btw., I am a bit curious. What does this linear system model?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! Really appreciate it. To answer your questions, yes, in the actual system (based on physical reasoning), I only expect one null vector. And the system is some sort of special generalization of steady-state mean-field theory for spins other than 1/2.

Comment: Might be able to use a divide-and-conquer approach as is done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6776/space-efficient-null-space-of-sparse-array).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Very interesting approach; I will keep it in mind (+1). However, I am not convinced that this will work out in OP's example: Szabolcs had a very tall matrix in the other post, so the nullspaces of  `top` can be expected to be rather small. However, this matrix here is a square $n \times n$-matrix, so `Nullspace[top]` will have at least $n$ elements... and I doubt that `Nullspace[top]` will be particularly sparse.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher All good points. The method I linked to would probably not be so good here, barring someone figuring out improvements that elude me (and perhaps simply do not exist).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher @DanielLichtblau thank you both for your suggestions! I got the chance to try both methods; the eigensystem with "Arnoldi" is incredibly fast (as opposed to the `NullSpace[]`, nearly 10 times) and chopping the matrix into smaller pieces method also works perfectly well for extremely large [square] cases, even though it is a bit slower. I most probably will keep trying both to the limit of my computational resources, but if I run into anything notable, I'll definitely update the post with it. Thank you both again very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Turning a comment into an answer.*

Apparently,

```
{lambda, u} = Eigensystem[NullMatrix, -1, Method -> {"Arnoldi"}];
```

works fine. `u[[1]]` seems to be the only null vector. Or do you expect more than one? Then you can do, e.g.,

```
{lambda, u} = Eigensystem[NullMatrix, -20, Method -> {"Arnoldi"}];
```

and check the vector `lambda` of eigenvalues for zero (or near-zero) entries.