# Hermite normal form and basis for the nullspace

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, linear-algebra

Define the Hermite Normal form $H$ for a matrix $A\in Z^{n\times n}$ as following:

$$H=UA$$ which in Mathematica is given as {u, h} = HermiteDecomposition[a]

Then for a system of homogeneous equations $Ax = [0]_{n}$ we normally compute a basis for the Nullspace of $A$, so any vector $x$ in $Ker(A)$ satisfies the system.

It results that $$Ax=[0]_{n} \rightarrow U^{-1}Hx =[0]_{n}  \rightarrow Hx = [0]_{n}$$

Then computing such a basis for $A$ can be done in terms of $H$, where $H$ is an upper triangular matrix, so at first glance NullSpace runs faster for $H$ instead of $A$.

But I'm not very familiarized with the time-complexity of Mathematica's implementation of HermiteDecomposition and Nullspace (this last one over a prime modulus). I don't think this would be a good idea for big dimensions, this is, big $n$.

The thing is that I need a $\textit{fast}$ and efficient method for computing a basis for the nullspace of $A$ over $F_2$ when $n$ is considerably big. What can I do?

---

P.D = As a recommendation from **MarcoB** the time lapses are given with an example matrix of size $100\times 100$:

NullSpace only call: $0.010054$s

HermiteDecomposition + NullSpace: $0.071549$s

LatticeReduce + NullSpace: $0.258836$s

where the NullSpace call is always taken over $F_2$.

Comment: Well, since both functions `HermiteDecomposition` and `Nullspace` are already available, couldn't you just make up some fake number with which to *try both out* and compare timings (e.g. with `RepeatedTiming`)?

Comment: I thought the same on my way to home. Will post time lapses as soon as I return to my research. Thanks.

Comment: @MarcoB: New day, new tests. Included time lapses for my method with an example squared matrix with $n=100$. When $n=2500$ it takes $1$ minute approximately to compute such a basis over $F_2$, so what can I do to optimize this procedure in Mathematica? Any alternative that I can implement and you can point me to? Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Thank you for running the tests. Please include the specific code and data you used in your question, so others can play around with it and chime in.

Comment: Why not just use `NullSpace[mat,Modulus->2]`?

Comment: I've discarded HermiteDecomposition or LatticeReduce for the time that both take. Yes, I'm using NullSpace with the Modulus option, as I'm working over $F_2$. But for i.e $n=10000\times 10000$ doesn't even finish passed $5$ minutes on my laptop. I've seen a different approach here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6776/space-efficient-null-space-of-sparse-array/6778#6778 based on partitioning the matrix into parts then computing separated nullspaces that finally give a vector that nullifies the matrix "mat".

Comment: I recall that method, at least on a good day. An alternative, that can be combined with it, is to use` ResourceFunction["BitStringNullSpace"]`. Here is [the corresponding documentation page](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BitStringNullSpace)

Comment: Memory is a clear boundary I forgot to mention. Now I can solve an arbitrary system witch coefficient matrix of order $10^4\times 10^4$ in $175$ seconds where finding the nullspace of a $3600\times 3600$ matrix with NullSpace over $F_2$ takes $185$ seconds. BitStringNullSpace is what I was looking for Daniel! A million thanks for mentioning it. Consider this thread solved.

Comment: Since it is a perfectly reasonable question and it should not go for lack of an answer, I'll post a brief community wiki response. You should feel free to edit it, especially if you want to add a specific example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least a few ways to improve matters. First is to use

```
NullSpace[mat,Modulus->2]
```

This is still memory hungry though. There is a splitting method, useful when the row count is large, that is shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6776/space-efficient-null-space-of-sparse-array/6778#6778).

Another method, which can be used in tandem with splitting, is to use bit strings to represent rows. The null space can then be extracted with `ResourceFunction["BitStringNullSpace"]`, documentation for which is [found here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BitStringNullSpace).